# HardReboot vs SoftReboot in Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.WatchdogBehavior?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

What does a HardReboot do?

What does a SoftReboot do?

Why would we use the one rather than the other?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the documentation it says SoftReboot performs a software reboot of the CLR. If there's no way to do it by software then it automaticaly will go by hardware.

[WatchdogBehavior Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.watchdogbehavior(v=vs.102).aspx)